# Passing http headers through a liferay portlet page

Tags: jsp, http-headers, liferay

In some portlet there is a page I want to access via ajax.
That page should set some http headers (at least, Status). 
As far as I can see, such headers are scrubbed.

The question is - how can I tell liferay to pass some specific headers?

Comment: You use JSR 286 portlets or JSR168 portlets?

Comment: JSR 286 introduced a new API called _serveResource_ specialized for handling XML (AJAX) requests. Here you're able to explicitly set HTTP headers. The most current Liferay releases provide support for this JSR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portlets by design cannot access the HTTP header - because you cannot predict, which portlets will be together on a page. Imagine one setting caching information to "revalidate immediately" while another portlet is happy with weekly revalidation - they all end up in the same page.

However, to overcome this limitation, Portletspec 2.0, i.e. JSR-286, came up with resource-serving as a separate lifecycle phase, specifically adding such a capability to portlets. However, this is separate from generating your "main" portlet output.

Mechanics will differ depending on the framework you use, for the plain portlet API look up serveResource as "home" suggested in the comment to your question. You have access to HTTP headers from the ResourceRequest/ResourceResponse parameters to that method, but - by design - not through ActionResponse or RenderResponse.